# Do workers reach diagonally?

Tags: a-game-of-dwarves

In general, or specifically for plants/food squares, do I need to make everything reachable in a '+' shape or can a worker harvest a plant in a corner?

Related question, can they walk over other plants or do I need to have a clear path between plants so they can harvest them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plants are both solid items and only accessible from cardinal directions, not diagonals.

You will have to place plants so there is a walkway to them.  While this does waste some fertile soil, you hardly need the extra squares in the long run.

The Fertilisation Stone does not require foot access, so you can place that behind the plants.  Just make sure the crafter has built it before you place the plants or he won't be able to reach it.